# Cannot set autocommit to 0 in my.ini file /(my.cfn file)

Tags: mysql, wampserver, my.cnf

I am using wamp server so my.ini file is the new my.cfn file.
I opened the file with an editor and i scrolled down untill i've seen

```
[mysqld]
```

after which i have typed

```
init_connect='SET autocommit=0'
```

then i have saved the file restarted my wamp server
started mySQL concol and entered the command

```
SELECT @@autocommit;
```

I got `@@autocommit | 1`
but to my understanding it should be zero if the autocommit is off.

Anybody understands whats going on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the answer of this page:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5035

especially here:

> [17 Aug 2004 11:20] Sergey Gluhov Looks like it's not a bug. If a user
>   has SUPER privilege, init_connect will not execute (otherwise if
>   init_connect will a wrong query no one can connect to server).
>
> Note, if init_connect is a wrong query, the connection is closing
>   without any errors and next command will clause 'lost connection'
>   error.

Maybe you're in the same situation?

Comment: Seems quite possible. Although I am connecting with the root user. Either way i think i will just figure something else out